# Postgresql fails to start on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-10.04

After I install and when restarting Postgresql I get this error. I have tried changing permissions accordingly(the owner of the all the directories and files in the error message is postgres) but to no avail. I have also completely purged and reinstalled different version of postgresql and get the same error on every install. I have tried starting as root and as postgres user.

"/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log" is empty.

```
root@ks27059:/var/lib/postgresql/9.2# /etc/init.d/postgresql start

* Starting PostgreSQL 9.2 database server                                      * Error:      
could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl start  
-D /var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log -s -o  -c 
config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/postgresql.conf" :
```

Comment: "the owner of the all the directories and files in the error message is postgres" Just glancing at my own install (9.1 on Ubuntu 12.04), root owns /usr/lib/postgresql and everything downstream of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748607/how-to-thoroughly-purge-and-reinstall-postgresql-on-ubuntu or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874754/eliminating-non-working-postgresql-installations-on-ubuntu-10-04-and-starting-af ; please read those questions

Comment: I had already tried both solutions mentioned in the questions linked by Ringer. I installed postgresql 9.2 from "add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql" using "aptitude install postgresql-9.2" and before that installation I had tried every possible way I found in google. My mistake for posting this in the wrong forum. I'm defeated and this question can be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is posted in the wrong forum I found an answer and I'd like to present it here for other people to see.

I had a Zend installation on my server which caused the error. I removed Zend and typed

```
"rm -r /usr/local/zend"
```

after which postgresql installed smoothly. I can't recommend this solution if you need your Zend but for me it worked.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I presume that the Zend install had a bundled copy of PostgreSQL? Or it had added entries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `/etc/ld.so.conf` that conflicted with system libraries? Otherwise I struggle to understand how it would've affected your PostgreSQL install.